# Multiply connection for mongo spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

i develop service with two connection for mongo db. This three classes configuration for connection:

```
@Data
@Configuration("mongoConfiguration")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${ona.connectionUrl}")
    private String onaConnectionUrl;
    @Value("${ona_singular.connectionUrl}")
    private String onaSingularConnectionUrl;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "draftOrderMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate draftOrderMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(draftOrderFactory());
    }

    @Bean(name = "SingularMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate SingularMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(SingularFactory());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory draftOrderFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(new ConnectionString(onaConnectionUrl));
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory SingularFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(new ConnectionString(onaSingularConnectionUrl));
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "mongo.cleaner.repository.draftOrder", mongoTemplateRef = "draftOrderMongoTemplate")
public class DraftOrderMongoConfig {}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "mongo.cleaner.repository.physyuriki", mongoTemplateRef = "SingularMongoTemplate")
public class SingularMongoConfig {}
```

it's working, but when app started i see in log this error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:27017
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

in application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
```

why i see error in log for strarting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.